# How to find current regex is used for pattern match after match.find() while using multiple patterns?

Tags: java, regex, match

I am using below regex to replace matched content.
My question is, is there any way to find which pattern current matcher is using (I mean matcher.find() for which of the given pattern)?

```
String[] searchRegex = new String[]{"(?i)<my:link([^>]+)/>", "(?i)<my:anotherLink([^>]+)/>", "\\$var([^>]+)\\$"};
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Stream.of(searchRegex).collect(joining("|")));
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(jsonObject.toString());
while (matcher.find()) {
  //how to find which pattern is used here to match content?
   String match = matcher.group();
   System.out.println(match);
  //here, need to use different replace content for each pattern
   matcher.appendReplacement(buffer, Matcher.quoteReplacement("<a href=\"wwww.google.com\">link to google</a>"));
    }
matcher.appendTail(buffer);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your final regex will look like

```
(?i)<my:link([^>]+)/>|(?i)<my:anotherLink([^>]+)/>
            ^^^^^^^                      ^^^^^^^
            group 1                      group 2
```

In current form you can just test if result of `group(1)` contains some text or is it null. Only one of `regex1|regex2` can be matched, so only one of those groups will contain text, other group will be holding `null`. So if `matcher.group(1)` will hold anything different than `null` then you first regex was matched, else second regex was matched.

Simplified demo:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("a(b)|a(c)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("abac");
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group(1) != null) {
        System.out.println(m.group() + " was matched by first pattern ");
    } else {
        System.out.println(m.group() + " was matched by second pattern ");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ab was matched by first pattern 
ac was matched by second pattern
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use groups. Groups are defined by enclosing a region of the regex in parenthesis.

Then you do:

```
m.find();
m.group(0); // the entire expression matched
m.group(1); // the first group, you start counting with index 1
```

however I recommend you give Google's REJ2 matcher a try
https://github.com/google/re2j

You can name your sub-groups, here's an example of a regular expression with named groups:

```
private static final String HTML_REGEX =
            "(?is)<td class=\"section_post_header\" colspan=\"2\"><h1><span style.*?>(?<displaynamefallback>.*?)</span></h1></td>.*?" +
                    "Download Links.*?" +
                    ".*<a href=\"(?<magneturl>magnet:\\?.*?)\" class=\"magnet\".*?" +
                    //"(<a href=\"(?<magneturl>magnet:\\?.*?)\" title=\"Magnet Link\".*?)?"+
                    ".*<a href=\"(?<torrenturl>http(s)?.*?\\.torrent)\" class=\"download_.\".*?" +
                    "(Torrent Info.*?title=\"(?<displayname>.*?)\".*?)?" +
                    "(<b>Torrent File:</b>\\s+(?<displayname2>.*?)<br.*?)?" +
                    "(<b>Torrent Hash:</b>\\s+(?<infohash>.*?)<br.*?)?" +
                    "<b>Filesize:</b>\\s+(?<filesize>.*?)<br.*?" +
"<b>Released:</b>\\s+(?<creationtime>.*?)<br";
```

If you look at the groups in parenthesis, I put names to them, right after I open a parenthesis `(?<myGroupName>regex here)`

which makes it a lot easier if you have to maintain the regex in the future.
Like the regex in the example which is used to scrape a website which can change.

Then I access groups by name

```
matcher.group("myGroupName")
```

If you get rid of a group, then you don't have to update the position of the remaining groups all over your code.